# How get dependencies gradle Java

Tags: java, gradle, gradle-plugin

How can get dependencies of current project, using Java ?
I try this code in Java class but result is empty:

```
class Example implements Plugin<Project> {
    void apply(Project project) {
             project.getConfigurations().getByName("runtime").getAllDependencies();        
        }
    }
```

Thanks for your answer JBirdVegas . I try write your example on Java:

```
List<String> deps = new ArrayList<>();
        Configuration configuration = project.getConfigurations().getByName("compile");
        for (File file : configuration) {
            deps.add(file.toString());
        }
```

But have error:

```
Cannot change dependencies of configuration ':compile' after it has been resolved.
```

when run gradle build

Comment: I put `apply plugin: Example` after `dependencies {...}` block and it worked

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're just missing a step to iterate over the found dependencies

Groovy:

```
class Example implements Plugin<Project> {
    void apply(Project project) {
        def configuration = project.configurations.getByName('compile')
        configuration.each { File file ->
            println "Found project dependency @ $file.absolutePath"
        }     
    }
}
```

Java 8:

```
import org.gradle.api.Plugin;
import org.gradle.api.Project;
import org.gradle.api.artifacts.Configuration;

public class Example implements Plugin<Project> {
    @Override
    public void apply(Project project) {
        Configuration configuration = project.getConfigurations().getByName("compile");
        configuration.forEach(file -> {
            project.getLogger().lifecycle("Found project dependency @ " + file.getAbsolutePath());
        });
    }
}
```

Java 7:

```
import org.gradle.api.Plugin;
import org.gradle.api.Project;
import org.gradle.api.artifacts.Configuration;

import java.io.File;

public class Example implements Plugin<Project> {
    @Override
    public void apply(Project project) {
        Configuration configuration = project.getConfigurations().getByName("compile");
        for (File file : configuration) {
            project.getLogger().lifecycle("Found project dependency @ " + file.getAbsolutePath());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i writed answer with example code  in body of my question))

Comment: @dmitryZaskovich it's not necessary for you to add the answer code to your question. Instead just select the answer as correct.

Comment: answer with code example having error when i use it on java( 
my java implementation is wrong?

Comment: i think your code is working if i use groovy . but how write its on java?

Comment: @dmitryZaskovich I added Java 7 & Java 8 examples of the same logic

Comment: why would anyone use groovy.